# update single document field in firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a document ref `user/userid23435534` and I want to update a single (document has several fields) field(nick) in that document.

I call this method: `ref.ref.update("nick","test123")` and I can see from logging that `ref.getpath()` is `user/userid23435534` indeed.

However, after calling this method, and getting success from my `OnSuccessListener` I still see that my field is not updated in the firestore database. What did I get wrong here?

EDIT:

```
public static void updateDocument(){
    final DocumentReference ref = db.collection("user").document("userid23435534");
    ref.update("nick", "test123" )    //logging shows that red.getPath is "user/userid23435534"
        .addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> {
            //success is called when calling method that runs this code
        }).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
            //....
        })
 }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show a more complete code sample.  There's not enough here to fully understand what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @DougStevenson I have now edited my question and added more code. If it's still unclear needs anyting else, please let me know.

Comment: I don't think that code will compile.  You're redefining `ref` inside the function that also has `ref` as a parameter.  Java won't allow that.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I edited my method. My ref is actually a parameter of the method, and is defined outside the method in another class. The collection and document parameter are set frm different parts of the program. I edited it to make the question a bit simplier. But I logged before&after the small change I made for SO to check it is the same values, and it is. @DougStevenson Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If this is not the exact code you're working with, I'm not so sure it's going to be helpful here.  On Stack Overflow, you should provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) that illustrates that problem, that anyone can reproduce on their own.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for your comment. I did some extensive debugging, turns out it is not a "firebase problem", but rather the problem is within wrapping the Task in a RxJava Completable emitter, where the onsuccess is never called. Thanks for your time, I will have to ask another question I think. Should I remove this question & reformulate to include rxjava problem and ask again?

Comment: In the future, you should show all the relevant code.  You didn't say anything about there being another layer of complexity around the sample you did show.

Comment: @DougStevenson I will try to, I am sorry for having wasted your time, and thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

I just ran this code in my local emulator, and it updates the document without problems:

```
DocumentReference ref = db.collection("56246892").document("uid");
ref.update("nick", "test123" ).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
        System.out.println("Updated");
    }
});
```

Are you sure the document already exists? That is required for `update()` to work. If you're not sure whether the document exists, use `set(..., SetOptions.merge())`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are 100% right, the code is correct and should work. I did some extensive debugging, turns out it is not a "firebase problem", but rather the problem is within wrapping the Task in a RxJava Completable emitter, where the onsuccess is never called. Thanks for your time, I will have to ask another question I think. Should I remove this question & reformulate to include rxjava problem and ask again?

Comment: This is one of the reasons we ask for an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): it puts the onus on you to isolate the problem in a way that allows us reproduce it with reasonable effort. Since the code you gave worked for me, it also would've worked for you. If you'd have tried that in a standalone program like I did, you should've seen that this code is unrelated to the problem, and hence, the problem must be elsewhere. This is key to becoming a more independent developer, and [creating MCVE's](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is a great tool for that.